# iOS CI fails with "CoreUI: CUICatalog: couldn't get 'kMGArtworkGraphicsFeatureSetFallbacks' from MGCopyAnswer got"

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, continuous-integration

Keep getting thousands of these logs in our CI system since upgrading to Xcode 7. Don't have the slightest clue what they could mean.

```
2015-09-16 13:44:36.286 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[5197:11683] CoreUI: CUICatalog: couldn't get 'kMGArtworkGraphicsFeatureSetClass' from MGCopyAnswer got '{
    ArtworkDeviceIdiom = pad;
    ArtworkDeviceScaleFactor = "-1";
    DevicePerformanceMemoryClass = 1;
}'
2015-09-16 13:44:36.287 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[5197:11683] CoreUI: CUICatalog: couldn't get 'kMGArtworkGraphicsFeatureSetFallbacks' from MGCopyAnswer got '{
    ArtworkDeviceIdiom = pad;
    ArtworkDeviceScaleFactor = "-1";
    DevicePerformanceMemoryClass = 1;
}'
2015-09-16 13:44:36.288 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[5197:11683] CoreUI: CUICatalog: couldn't get 'kMGArtworkGraphicsFeatureSetClass' from MGCopyAnswer got '{
    ArtworkDeviceIdiom = pad;
    ArtworkDeviceScaleFactor = "-1";
    DevicePerformanceMemoryClass = 1;
}'
```

x 1000

Comment: Seeing this when building from Xamarin Studio via mtouch. I used to get 30 build warnings now I get 700.

Comment: I get over 16,000 warnings! It depends on how many XIB files you have.

This has something with using iOS 9.0 Simulator.  When I choose iOS 7.1 or iOS 8.4 for the simulator O/S, then I no longer get the extra warnings.

Comment: I had the same problem but still cannot remove those warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Same here. I get 16400 warnings when I build with Xamarin Studio. I had no issues before upgrading XCode 7 and latest XS:

Answer (score 1):

I have got small 13800 warnings out of this... as long as my reputation isn't high enough to comment questions (or answers) directly, I have to write in this way :(

I'm just glad at the moment, that I can work with my app on a device with the simulator.

Transfoming my project from Xamarin.iOS to unified API just didn't work out partly because of the missing "Migrate to Xamarin.iOS Unified API" (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/updating_ios_apps/) button in my Xamarin Studio and partly because the manually way to do this just had unsolvable problems with missing relations of my xibs in xCode.
But that doesn't matter anyway because those warnings were there even when running into build errors with the unified API.

My build problems overall were solved thanks to this:
[Codesign error in Xamarin Studio 5.9.7 (build 9) and Xamarin.iOS 9.0.1.18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647589/codesign-error-in-xamarin-studio-5-9-7-build-9-and-xamarin-ios-9-0-1-18)

Any suggestions how to eliminate those warnings are highly welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue plus the app would no longer launch in the simulator.   I was able to fix this by changing the architecture from i386 to x86_64.

In Xamarin, it's under your project options -> Build -> iOS Build -> Advanced tab (on right) -> Supported architectures dropdown.

Comment: For those wondering about the third option, i386+x86_64, setting it did not eliminate the warnings, but did at least fix the issue where the app would no longer launch in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and being tracked on Xamarin forums. Expect a fix soon

> Non-public Bug 33706 - [iOS] Storyboards produce many warnings similar to: "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool: 2015-09-04 18:01:03.651 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[72838:13678534] CoreUI: CUICatalog: couldn't get 'kMGArtworkGraphicsFeatureSetClass' from MGCopyAnswer got '{ (CollectionView)". These warnings can be ignored for now. The problem is that Xamarin is currently surfacing diagnostic messages from ibtool that are not surfaced by the default Xcode build process.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50971/stable-release-xamarin-ios-9-0-ios-9-0-upstream-release/p1

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there are no warnings or errors with your storyboard. I think it should be a bug of XCode, but you can fix by yourself by correcting the problem I said. For me, it goes away.

Comment: Not using storyboards and no reported warnings in my nib files.