# Codesign error in Xamarin Studio 5.9.7 (build 9) and Xamarin.iOS 9.0.1.18

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have upgraded Xamarin Studio to the latest version in the beta channel. When I try to run the app I get the following error:

```
Signing application
codesign -v --force --sign "[hex]" --entitlements "/Users/[username]/devel/git/[app]/bin/iPhone/Debug/[app].xcent" "/Users/[username]/devel/git/[app]/bin/iPhone/Debug/[app].app"
/Users/[username]/devel/git/[app]/bin/iPhone/Debug/[app].app: invalid resource specification rule(s)
codesign exited with code 1
```

Why could this be? And how can I get around it?

- Xamarin Studio 5.9.7 (build 9)
- Xamarin.iOS 9.0.1.18 (Business Edition)
- Xcode 7.0 (8227) Build 7A220

The closest clue I got was https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28480/upload-to-appstore-failed-contains-an-invalid-key-cfbundleresourcespecification-in-bundle , but I can't find the option in Xamarin Studio mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a known issue mentioned [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/50971/stable-release-xamarin-ios-9-0-ios-9-0-upstream-release).
Partial workaround did the trick for me.

*Non-public Bug 31424 - [Xamarin Studio] [iOS] Classic API on Mac only: "Resource rules files "" not found". Partial workaround: Enable "Project Options -> General -> Use MSBuild build engine (unsupported for this project type)" and clean and rebuild the project. (The MSBuild build engine does now work for many Classic API projects.)*

Comment: THANK YOU. The workaround did the trick for me as well. You saved my day. :) (Tried downgrading to earlier versions of Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin Studio and Xcode beta, but only ran into other codesign issues.)

Comment: Sadly the workaround did not work for me. Instead I get error:The attribute "xmlns" in element <InterfaceDefinition> is unrecognized.

Comment: It didn't work for me either. After doing that I get a: CSC: error CS1703: An assembly `System' with the same identity has already been imported. Consider removing one of the references...

Comment: @NikoZarzani You just to have remove one or more duplicates imports. I had to remove <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> from a couple of .csproj files.

Comment: Actually in my XXXXX.csproj I have just one <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> and one <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MonoTouch.CSharp.targets" />. Removing one of them solves the issue, however then I get a crash after my first login screen: `_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15) `

Comment: Follows the exception:  `Exception: Failed to marshal the Objective-C object 0x1757b910 (type: AppDelegate). Could not find an existing managed instance for this object, nor was it possible to create a new managed instance (because the type 'XXXXX.AppDelegate' does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument).
2015-09-23 09:58:25.344 Stacktrace:   at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.MissingCtor (IntPtr ptr, IntPtr klass, System.Type type, MissingCtorResolution resolution) [0x00046] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2077/d8e9592a/source/maccore/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:763`

Answer (score 1):

you have to edit the project *.csproj file with textedit and remove the xmlns="" in the

Then proceed with the answer from teahaige

Answer (score 0):

Gagagu's answer worked for me. I had multiple lines like the following in my .csproj:

```
<InterfaceDefinition Include="xyz.xib" xmlns="" />
```

Removing the `xmlns=""` parts, then setting the MSBuild build engine option, and then cleaning and rebuilding the project did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this issue by upgrading my version of Xamarin to the **5.9.7 build 12 beta**.

There is a ticket relating to this on Bugzilla (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34384#c2) so this issue should be corrected when that build hits the main release channel.

In the mean time you can install the 5.9.7 build 12 beta release if you change to the beta channel in Xamarin's upgrade options.